# Can i put an "Element, class or id" instead of "window" in this case?

Tags: resize, window, height

```
$(window).resize(function(){
                $('.container').css('height', $(window).height());
            });
```

Can i get the resized(changed) height of .container?

It doesnt work.

```
.css('height', $(".container").height());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.css('height',$('.container').height($(window).height()));
```

Comment: it works :) but when i use it with var, doesnt work.  Can i put $('.container').height($(window).height()) in a variable?

Comment: Sorry about late respond . https://codepen.io/jh-ko/pen/Eqpbjz it is an example. I want to have the result and current px of var "winHeight"-"contHeight". The browser will resize. If i wrote 100% instead of var "winHeight" it works. But i want to calculate with another class or id height ..

Comment: Change `winHeight` to `window.innerHeight` in resize function